# select one image from a specific month of an imageCollection in google earth engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I would like to keep in *Landsat 8 32-Day NDVI Composite* `imageCollection` one layer in decembre between 2014 and 2017. Is there any way to do a variable filter ? Or a filter on month ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For filtering a specific month, you can use `ee.Filter.calendarRange` within the `filter` method of the `ImageCollection`:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12,12,'month'));
```

The result gives you an `ImageCollection` containing the following images:

```
0: Image LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20131219 (1 band)
1: Image LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20141219 (1 band)
2: Image LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20151219 (1 band)
3: Image LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI/20161218 (1 band)
```

As to selecting a specific image, you can either do the same filtering on the year or convert the `ImageCollection` to a list and select the image you want.

HTH